# Was “who’s she, the cat’s grandmother” common in Scotland?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage, nineteenth-century-english, scottish-english

My mother’s retired Scottish nanny, who was born in 1888, and grew up near Ullapool, on Loch Broom, would say this. She also took care of me when I was a child. She would correct me when I spoke of someone as “she” with “who’s she, the cat’s grandmother?”
Of course I thought it was funny but the lesson sunk in. I use it with my grandchildren now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who's 'she', the cat's mother?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403263/whos-she-the-cats-mother) Also see [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/04/cats-mother.html) and _"In Kent, and by Kentish folk, the same thought is expressed by "She is the cat's grandmother._" [1878 _Notes & Queries_]

Comment: @Heartspring The other question mentions this expression but it doesn't actually explain where it was used or anything about Scotland really. The inclusion of the expression over there is literally a parenthetical.

Comment: @Laurel - If by 'over there' you mean the UK, the linked question certainly does refer to it. My mother (Yorkshire - Derbyshire) used "Who's she - the cat's mother?", but I have heard the 'grandmother' version, I think from a person with Scottish roots.

Comment: I don't think it's specifically Scottish but I have heard it used in Scotland. What precisely does "was it common?" mean?

Comment: @KateBunting I'm talking about the information provided in the linked question's answers.